# Get-AzConnectedMachineExtension returns True for enableAutomaticUpgrade when Null is expected

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-arc

#### Description

The `enableAutomaticUpgrade` property on Azure arc machine extensions have three possible values:

- `True`
- `False`
- `Null`

This is based on the information provided for that type: [`IMachineExtension.EnableAutomaticUpgrade`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.powershell.cmdlets.connectedmachine.models.api20221227.imachineextension.enableautomaticupgrade?view=az-ps-10#microsoft-azure-powershell-cmdlets-connectedmachine-models-api20221227-imachineextension-enableautomaticupgrade).
My assumption is that "`Null`" is a representation of "**Not Supported**" state in Azure portal.

#### Issue

While working with `Get-AzConnectedMachineExtension` cmdlet, I noticed that the `enableAutomaticUpgrade` property returns `True` when the value for this property in Azure portal is "**Not Supported**". Needless to say, that is inaccurate, and a `Null` would of have been more appropriate or similar representation.

The issue might be coming from the `True` being the default value for the property. But that should only be the case if the extension supports automatic upgrade in the first place. There is should be a return to indicate "Not Supported" (`Null` for example)

**Example**

An extension example would be `Microsoft.Azure.AzureDefenderForServers.MDE.Windows` extension.

I initially an issue in GitHub [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/24380) as well but StackOverflow was always good to me :) .

#### Ask

1. I would appreciate if someone can confirm in fact there is an issue with cmdlet as I described it.
2. If there is any possible way in PowerShell to know the state of an Azure Arc extension when it's "Not Supported" (assuming there isn't an issue in # 1 above and I am just not doing it right)

Comment: Have you tried with `Get-AzConnectedMachine` command? @Yousef Imran

Comment: I have. But it doesn't serve my purpose here. My goal is to get information at the extension level. The Get-AzConnectedMachine works at the machine/agent level. I looked at the properties available in that command and it has one property that may of have been of a value but it is deprecated "Extension: Machine Extensions information (deprecated field)" found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.powershell.cmdlets.connectedmachine.models.api20221227.imachine?view=az-ps-10 .